# Помогите разобраться как работает jQuery на сайте

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

Здравствуйте!

Помогите, пожалуйста разобраться с фронтенд частью страницы: `https://auto.ru/cars/used/add/

Не могу понять, где находятся .js  скрипты, откуда работает Ajax и где все обработчики событий.

На странице подключена лишь библиотека jQuery. Остальных скриптов внутри страницы и путей до скриптов в других файлов не нашёл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

открываем view-source:https://auto.ru/cars/used/add/
и листаем в самый низ, там 2 файла
1) https://i.auto.ru/js/spy/spy.js
2) https://yastatic.net/autoru-frontend-poffer/0.0.392/bundles/common/_common.js